# Arrow Syntax VS ES5 function scope

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was trying to experiment with some JavaScript code. I am not sure why the ES6 syntax fails.

```js
String.prototype.spacify = function() {
  console.log(this.split('').join(' '));
}

'hello world'.spacify();
```

**^^ This works GREAT!
But, When I do this**

```js
String.prototype.spacify = () => {
  console.log(this.split('').join(' '));
}

'hello world'.spacify();
```

**When I convert the function to Arrow function, I get this.split is not defined. I didn't understand. Is arrow syntax doing something special with scoping?**

Please enlighten!

Comment: A google reveals many takes on `this` https://derickbailey.com/2015/09/28/do-es6-arrow-functions-really-solve-this-in-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

In [**arrow function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) the context of `this` refers to the outer `this`. Here the `this` of the function `test` is equal to the `this` in the arrow function.

arrow function doesn't create it's own context, it just takes the outer context

```
function test() {


     String.prototype.spacify = () => {
         console.log(this.split('').join(' '));
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In arrow functions, the scope does not change.

Meaning:

```
const globalThis = this;

String.prototype.spacify = () => {
  // this === globalThis
  ...
}
```

Comment: That's not quite right. Scope and `this` are related but are not the same. Of course arrow functions have their own scope, just like any other function.

Comment: @FelixKling interesting, can you elaborate a bit more?